# "Problem of points (POP)" explanation

Tags: probability

Quite recently, there was a question related to "Problem of Points" at MSE.  I did some literature survey on POP in the internet and found explanations using an example of coin toss.  I have been trying to get an explanation in terms of a rolling a die.

Two players keep rolling a fair six sided die and player A wins a point if 2 appears and player B wins a point if 6 appears.  The player who wins 3 points first wins the $100 wager.  Suddenly the game gets interrupted and the score is 2-1.  How do you divide the stakes.

The solution somebody posted was a split of $75 to $25 and the rational was that they play two more games and the future states of winning the rounds of additional two games was (2,2),(2,6),(6,2) and (6,6) and that there is a 3:1 ratio split.  But I wonder if we should count this way.  I am not challenging the answer but seek explanation under the following rational

A)Probability of a 2 = 1/6, B)Probability of a 6 = 1/6 and C)Probability no one wins = 2/3

Unlike coin toss where there are only two outcomes head or tail, rolling die has three outcomes 2 appears, 6 appears and other numbers appear.  Could someone give me clarity of how this would change the way the stakes are divided or should we only be considering winning?

Comment: Note: The word that you want is the noun *rationale* ‘reason, justification’, not the adjective *rational*.

Comment: I am non-native speaker of English and I apologize for misconception on using rationale.

Comment: No need to apologize: a good many native speakers make exactly the same mistake. My comment was purely for information, not a criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability that Player $A$ wins if they continue playing from the point at which the game was interrupted. If the first roll is a $2$, Player $A$ wins immediately; if it’s a $6$, the score is tied at $2$-$2$; and if it’s anything else, the situation is unchanged. In the first case Player $A$ wins with probability $1$; in the second case the game is even, so each player wins with probability $\frac12$; and in the third case Player $A$ wins with probability $p$. Thus,

$$p=\frac16\cdot1+\frac16\cdot\frac12+\frac23\cdot p=\frac23p+\frac14\;,$$

so $\dfrac13p=\dfrac14$, and $p=\dfrac34$. A $3:1$ split of the stakes in favor of Player $A$ is therefore fair.

Comment: Thanks Dr Scott.  Wonderful explanation!!!

Comment: @satish: You’re welcome, and thank *you*.